# How did the Millennium Falcon escape discovery?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

Given that the Millennium Falcon was using sublight ion drives when careening at the bridge of the Avenger (Captain Needa's ship), why could they not track the ion drive emissions and see where it stops? If the ion trail just ceases to exist on the "back" of the bridge area, send a TIE fighter to take a look.

Alternatively, there should also have been some fairly substantial sound from the hull when the manual grapple (And/or magnetic grapple) was employed to bring the MF to the sudden halt necessary. (or even some stormtrooper looking out a random porthole)

Vader

> Alert all commands.  Calculate every possible destination along their last known trajectory.

That would seem to indicate to start at point of origin and go out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Falcon doesn't have many distinct features - it could have easily blended into the ship's hull at a cursory eye view - and no one had any reason to believe Solo would hook himself onto the Star Destroyer (who WOULD try something that insane?), so no one was really looking for him right there.

The sound of the Falcon itself careening over the Star Destroyer could have distracted the bridge crew long enough for them not to notice the sound of the ship locking onto the larger ship with magnets (speculation I know, but that's what I've got to work with).

And even if they were 'starting' from the Star Destroyer, no one would expect the Falcon to be AT that point - every ship would head out from that point forward, but without any reason to look at the Star Destroyer itself, they'd pass by it quickly.

In short - It was a crazy enough idea to work (and magnets aren't that loud, apparently).

Comment: Any comment on the main part of the question, the ion trail?

Comment: @JohnP - That actually ties up quite nicely. If the ion trail stops right alongside the Star Destroyer then that would *strongly* suggest that they've gone into hyperspace. The reality is that it stops because **they're still there** but who could have predicted that?

Comment: @JohnP Only a comment, since it's the speculationist of speculation. For one, if they had reason to believe the Falcon had cloaking capability, they must have also assumed that their ion trail could also be cloaked. And two, we can assume the Star Destroyer may have been moving during the pursuit of the Falcon, meaning the end of that trail would have been the point at which they were when the Falcon latched on, a fair distance behind them.  And, what Richard just said also makes sense.

Comment: I can grant @Richard the point, but they had no reason to suspect cloaking (There's a quote to the contrary, actually).

Comment: @JohnP If I recall the quote correctly, it's an assertion that they don't believe they have that capability, rather than an absolute certainty.  Though I concede that cloaking would be stretching the idea pretty far, and I do prefer Richard's explanation.

Comment: @JohnP - According to the Clone Wars canon, the scimitar (a substantially smaller ship than the falcon) had a cloaking device; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scimitar

Comment: @Richard - Interesting. According to that, Slave I also had a cloaking device, which would have obviated the need to hide in the trash.

Comment: @JohnP Maybe parking on the Avenger was too expensive for Boba Fett.

Comment: I'm sure that Vader had parking validation...

Comment: @Richard, That article also notes that the Scimitar is a prototype. Also, in many science fiction settings (though I can't comment directly on SW), cloaking a smaller ship is easier than cloaking a bigger ship, so the Scimitar being smaller than the Falcon doesn't give any weight to the Falcon's possibility of having a cloaking device.

Comment: @BrianS - Except that the canon quote is "no ship that small has a cloaking device". Clearly a cloak is (at least as far as the Imperial officer is aware) a bulky device.

Comment: @Richard, Fair enough. Then I refer back to the "Scimitar is a prototype" comment. :)

Comment: @BrianS - A prototype that was over 30 years old by the time the Falcon makes its escape.

Comment: @Richard, A prototype created in a prequel (thus inconsistencies are expected) in a setting where technological advancement over time is apparently dodgy at best. You also have to ask how effective the Scimitar's cloak was (did it _really_ work as it needed to over sustained periods of time, and were there any detrimental side-effects?), and how well-known was it? As an analogy, there are many medical advancements in the real world that the general public is not aware of -- in our case it's because they haven't yet been vetted, but the Scimitar's technology could be unknown for other reasons.

Comment: "The sound of the Falcon itself careening over the Star Destroyer could have distracted the bridge crew" -- we in the movie theater hear sounds in space, but is it really canon that crews of one ship can hear other ships passing by them through a vacuum?

Comment: @Hypnosifl I can't think of a proper citation, but I think starships in the Star Wars universe actually ARE equipped with sensors that create sound feedback on surrounding ships, though really, what would have distracted them would be the Falcon sweeping by and nearly killing them  all, less the sound.  And, since we in the theater didn't hear the Falcon lock on, obviously nobody on the bridge did either.

Comment: @TheCloakingDebate The Scimitar may have been a prototype ship, but the Falcon is an Amalgam of all the best parts that various smugglers had cobbled together over many, many years.  It's known to have a hyperdrive faster than capital Imperial ships, and while it would be surprising to find out it had cloaking capability, it fits with its profile (and remember, it's not important whether or not it DID have cloaking, more important was that the Imperial Officer thought it MIGHT have cloaking.)